# alternative <base href=""> tag

Tags: html, angular-ui-router, href

Is it possible to have an alternative `<base>` tag to use conditionally?

I have the standard:

```
<base href="/" />
```

But for one route it would be awesome if I could use the base `href` as:

```
<base href="/path/" />
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Well, yes. I guess. Did you try?

Comment: I'm not sure how to, just having 2 base tags in my head wont do much - I'm not sure how i would tell when to use one over of the other.

Comment: Two base? Oh... I just get it.

Comment: Conditionally you can do I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditionally using Angular, yes. Using `ng-href`:

```
<base ng-href="{{base_href}}" />
```

And use Angular Router to populate the values for `base_href`. The `href` is a HTML Attribute, which is static, while `ng-href` is same as the former, but it is an Angular Directive.